# Python numbers won't randomize

Tags: python

I have been making a fighting game but the damage won't randomize.

```
from random import randint
import time
#playerHealth = 20 
#trollHealth = 10
#dragonHealth = 15
#playerDamage = randint(0,5)
#trollDamage = randint(0,4)
#dragonDamage = randint(0,7)
#slay = True
#######Variables.

#print("""Random fight""")




def fight(enemy):

    playerH = 20 
    trollH = 10
    dragonH = 15
    playerD = randint(0,5)
    trollD = randint(0,4)
    dragonD = randint(0,7)
    slay = True

    if enemy == "troll":
        enemyH = trollH
        enemyD = trollD
    elif enemy == "dragon":
        enemyH = dragonH
        enemyD = dragonD
    else:
        print("Invalid")

    print"You are fighting a ", enemy
    while slay:
        print"Your health:",playerH
        print"Enemy health:",enemyH
        time.sleep(1)

        #########When player is attacking###########################
        if playerD == 5 or playerD == 4:
            print"You deal",playerD,"damage points. A critical hit!"
            time.sleep(1)
            enemyH = enemyH - playerD
            print"The",enemy,"has",enemyH,"health points remaining."
            time.sleep(1)
        elif playerD == 0:
            print"You missed and deal 0 damage points."
            time.sleep(1)
            enemyH = enemyH - playerD
            print"The enemy has",enemyH,"health points remaining."
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print"You deal",playerD,"damage points."
            time.sleep(1)
            enemyH = enemyH - playerD
            print"The enemy has ", enemyH, "health points remaining."
            time.sleep(1)
        #############################################################

        ########When troll is attacking##############################
        if enemy == "troll":
            if enemyD == 4:
                print"The troll deals 4 damage points. A critical hit!"
                time.sleep(1)
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                time.sleep(1)
            elif enemyD == 0:
                print"The troll missed and deals 0 damage points."
                time.sleep(1)
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print"The troll deals",enemyD,"damage points."
                time.sleep(1)
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                time.sleep(1)
        ##############################################################

        ##########When dragon is attacking############################        
        if enemy == "dragon":
            if enemyD == 6 or enemyD == 7:
                print"The dragon deals",enemyD,"damage points. A critical hit!"
                time.sleep(1)
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                time.sleep(1)
            elif enemyD == 0:
                print"The dragon missed deals 0 points of damage."
                time.sleep(1)
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print"The dragon deals",enemyD,"damage points."
                time.sleep(1)
                playerH = playerH - enemyD
                print"You have",playerH,"health points remaining."
                time.sleep(1)
        ###############################################################

        if enemyH == 0:
            slay = False
            print("You won the battle!")
        elif playerH == 0:
            slay = False
            print("You lost the battle. Better luck next time.")
##############################End of function##################################


#########Begining of game############################
enemyTest = True
print("Prepare yourself for battle.")
time.sleep(1)
while enemyTest:
    enemy = raw_input("Would you like to fight a 'dragon' or a 'troll'? ")
    enemy = enemy.lower()
    if enemy == "troll" or enemy == "dragon":
        enemyTest = False
    else:
        print("Invalid.")
        time.sleep(1)

if enemy == "troll":
    fight(enemy)
elif enemy == "dragon":
    fight(enemy)
else:
    print("Restart the program.")
    time.sleep(3)








#To fix:
#Enemy still attacks after death(test for death after each attack. Function?
#Damage doesn't vary
#Speed too fast at parts
```

In the function I want it to keep randomizing the damage so I set a randint for each character. However, for example let's say I want to fight a dragon the battle will start and if the player deals 4 damage first and the dragon deals 2 damage first they will only deal 4 and 2 damage throughout the whole battle. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Post only relevant code. I'm guessing it's about 1-3 lines. And you seem to be missing some spacing in your strings.

Answer (score 2):

You assign  randint values in the following function:

```
def fight(enemy):
    playerH = 20 
    trollH = 10
    dragonH = 15
    playerD = randint(0,5)
    trollD = randint(0,4)
    dragonD = randint(0,7)

import random
rand_value=   random.randint(0,10)

for i in range(5):
    print rand_value
2
2
2
2
2


for i in range(5):
    print random.randint(0,5)
2
1
3
2
5
```

Then you enter the  `while slay loop` so the value never changes in that  loop.
You need to set the `randint` values in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

You pick the damage amount with this line:

```
 playerD = randint(0,5)
```

And then a few lines *after* that you enter your loop:

```
 while slay:
```

You never set the damage again after that, so it never changes.

Basically, you're rolling a dice before you start playing, then leaving it on the table and glancing at it every time you want a new number. You need to pick it up and roll it again during the game, i.e. pick a new random number inside the loop.

I'm somewhat reminded of [this xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/221/).